# How to drag and drop an image on top of another image HTML5

Tags: html, css

I need to be able to drag and drop an image on top of another image using HTML5. Can anyone help?

All I have found are tutorials on how to drag and drop an image into a `div`, not another image.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your code and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script>
  function allowDrop(ev)
 {
 ev.preventDefault();
   }

   function drag(ev)
   {
   ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
   }

    function drop(ev)
   {
   ev.preventDefault();
  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
   ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)"
  ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

 <img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true"
 ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be late to answer now but there's a solution here in case it can help, he gives a clever trick to do it and links a jsfiddle:
[Drag and Drop from image onto another image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474553/drag-and-drop-from-image-onto-another-image/37488626)