# Drag and Drop from image onto another image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I wanted to drag and drop image onto another image.
I cannot figure it out.. I want to drag icons image, onto droppable briefcase and the icons will stay there.. my codes.. I want the icons image to be onto briefcase image not outside of briefcase image.

### Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#dragIcons img").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    refreshPositions: true,
    drag: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.addClass("draggable");
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      ui.helper.removeClass("draggable");
      var image = this.src.split("/")[this.src.split("/").length - 1];
      if ($.ui.ddmanager.drop(ui.helper.data("draggable"), event)) {
        alert(image + " dropped.");
      } else {
        alert(image + " not dropped.");
      }
    }
  });
  $("#briefcase").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      if ($("#briefcase img").length == 0) {
        $("#briefcase").html("");
      }
      ui.draggable.addClass("dropped");
      $("#briefcase").append(ui.draggable);
    }
  });
});
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="dragIcons">
  <img src="assets/img/gebiz.png">
  <img src="assets/img/b2b.png">
</div>
<div id="briefcase">
  <img width="600px" height="auto" src="assets/img/briefcase.svg">
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.draggable {
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.dropped {
  position: static !important;
}

#dragIcons {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 430px;
}

#briefcase {
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  height: auto;
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for this? I'm also assuming that you're using jQueryUI  - do you have the CDN linked in your index.html ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, I have created a jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/xInfinityMing/0up3e08p/# I wanted the icons to be inside the briefcase not outside..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `<img>` tag in the `#briefcase` div.  Instead, make the background of the div as the image and make its position `absolute`.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0up3e08p/5/) - you'll have to fix the CSS positioning of the icons, but the main idea is there.

Comment: Thanks, It's work! How to I do highlight image on hover and dropped in different colours?

Comment: Hi @YiMing glad it worked! Typically on SO, you mark this as correct and create a new question for your other requests.